# ASP.NET Terminating due to Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core

The script crashes over timeout. Where can I customize? I understand that in the application itself in web.config you need to register something like

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="10000" />
</system.web>
```

If I understand correctly, then I don’t understand where exactly to put this tag?
I have this structure in web.config

```
configuration
    location 
         system.webServer
              security
              handlers
              aspNetCore
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this sitewide as a child of the configuration node.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/web/

You can also configure them with more granularity, as a child of your location node(s)

```
 <location path="foo">
    <system.web>
        <!-- Set execution timeout to 6 minutes -->
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```